# Covid-19 travel from UK to France

Tags: uk, paperwork, international-travel, france, covid-19

For travel from the UK to France after a full course of Covid-19 does one need a PCR test?

Comment: Please do not post in the answers fields unless you have a real answer. It will only be deleted.

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean a “full course of COVID-19 vaccine” or if you mean “infected and recovered”?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

“ Travellers who are fully vaccinated do not need an essential reason to travel to France and do not need to self-isolate on arrival. Fully vaccinated travellers will need to present the following documents:

- those travelling aged 11 years old or over, will need evidence of a negative PCR test result taken within 72 hours of departure, or a negative antigen test result taken within 48 hours of departure
- a completed ‘sworn statement’ (déclaration sur l’honneur) form self-certifying they are not suffering from symptoms associated with coronavirus and have not been in contact with confirmed cases in the preceding fortnight. This can be found on the French government’s website
- proof of vaccination status”

Source: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france/entry-requirements

Comment: (+1) The French government announced some changes but official websites have not been updated and it's not clear when they will be implemented and whether they will change anything for vaccinated travellers. In any case, a PCR test is strictly speaking not required as such as an antigen test will do as well.